# BatchFile Xcopy is not copying my file to the source location

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have a batch file and I am trying to copy a file from the local machine to the a network location.  My file is not being copied from destination to source location.

The contents of my batch file is:

```
set TEST_HOME=%~dp0
cd %~dp0
E:
SET PATH=%PATH%;e:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\IEDriverServer\32bit
SET PATH=%PATH%;e:\Python27;e:\Python27\scripts

cd %~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1

set PYTHONPATH=%~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1

nosetests "%~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestSuite\suite_regression.py" 

timeout 10

: Copy selenium_report to storage-1
xcopy /y %~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore_Automated_GUI_Regression_TestReport \\STORAGE-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore\Selenium VM\IE11

timeout 10

: Email the selenium report
e:\python27\python "%~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\Email\email_selenium_report.py"
```

The line which is not copying the file is:

```
xcopy /y %~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore_Automated_GUI_Regression_EditProject_Grouping_IE11_TestReport \\STORAGE-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore\Selenium VM\IE11
```

There is something wrong with the Xcopy syntax i think.

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: Use double quote in the pathes :xcopy /y "%~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore_Automated_GUI_Regression_TestReport" "\\STORAGE-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore\Selenium VM\IE11"

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Comment: ...just a side note: usually, the directory you are copying files from is called the source, and the directory where you are copying files to is called destination...

Comment: @RiazLadhani It is definitely better to use `cd /D "%~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1"`. Run in a command prompt window `cd /?` for help on this command and what option `/D` is for. Run in same command prompt window `xcopy /?` for help on this command and `cmd /?` for help on Windows command interpreter explaining in last paragraph of last help page when a directory/file name must be enclosed in double quotes. On using `xcopy` to copy 1 or more files into a destination directory, specify the destination directory path with ``\`` at end.